# InverseProperty Entity Framework 7

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I am facing a problem with EF7 inverse property. There are two entities that are connected like this.

```
public class Employee
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
    }

public class Review
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public virtual Employee Employee { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public Employee Manager { get; set; }
 }
```

I want to access a list of the reviews when I start to query my employees, so I tried to do this:

```
public class Employee
    {
        public Employee()
        {
            Reviews = new List<Review>();
        }
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [InverseProperty("Employee")]
        public virtual ICollection<Review> Reviews { get; set; }
    }
```

With this, the query is not well made and return this error:

`Invalid column name 'EmployeeId1'`.

This is the part of the query where is the error:

```
SELECT [ua].[Id], [r].[EmployeeId], [r].[EmployeeId1], [r1].[EmployeeId], [r1].[EmployeeId1]
FROM [UserAssessment] AS [ua]
LEFT JOIN [Review] AS [r] ON [ua].[ReviewId] = [r].[Id]
LEFT JOIN [Review] AS [r1] ON [ua].[ReviewId] = [r1].[Id]
```

Anyone know what can I do?

**UPDATE**

This statement is generating the query:

```
return this.DbSet
.Include(ua => ua.Employee).ThenInclude(t => t.Role)
.Include(ua => ua.Review).ThenInclude(rt => rt.ReviewType)
.Include(ua => ua.Review).ThenInclude(rt => rt.Manager).ThenInclude(r => r.Role)
```

I have to access with those same `includes` because lazy loading is not available on EF7 yet.

Comment: Show the error message and command that causes it. On your end, you could also examine the generated SQL to see what it shows.

Comment: What code generates that statement? Do you use Code-First? Did you try to create fresh DB with your model?

Comment: @Edin, I've updated the question with the statement that generates the query.. I'm using code-first and I've not tried to generated the database again because I'm not changing or adding any fields and the table is already used in other parts of the system, so I can do a drastic modification like that.

Comment: EF will use Employee as Navigation property for the FK EmployeeId, and then needs another FK for the navigation property Manager - it will create the FK EmployeeId1 for this.

Comment: Is EmployeeId1 the manager's ID?  Your relationship does not know which employee to use maybe

Answer (score 0):

You need the **InverseProperty** on both the Employee and Review

```
public class Review
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [InverseProperty("Reviews")]
    public Employee Employee { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public Employee Manager { get; set; }
 }

public class Employee
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [InverseProperty("Employee")]
        public ICollection<Review> Reviews { get; set; }
    }
```

Should work. I have a similar setup where it creates the navigation without creating any new fields. If this doesn't work let me know and I'll spin up a test project.

Also note, that EF7 currently ignores *virtual* and this does not have meaning like it did in EF6.